# How do you address clergy in a given circumstance and manner?

Tags: honorifics

I want to ask a question about using titles, but I think it is too broad to be asked here.

My question is this: under what circumstance and in what manner should you address Christian clergy?

Do you address them by their personal titles, such as mister, mistress, or miss? Do you address them by their professional titles, such as Doctor or Professor, if they happen to have a PhD degree in Theology? Do you address them by "Your Eminence" or "Your Reverence" or "Your Grace"? Or maybe all those titles apply to formal situations, so in informal situations, you simply refer to them by their personal names, even though you would never address a professor by his/her first name or last name without the "Professor" as a prefix?

I also wish to know how to address Buddhist and Taoist and Jewish and Muslim clergy.

Comment: This varies along denominational lines. "Father", "Reverend", or "Pastor", are fairly common; I believe most clergymen would probably rather **not** be called "Your Eminence" or "Your Reverence" or "Your Grace".

Comment: Christian clergy have differing conventions, depending on matters of sect traditions and status among clergy. Catholic priests are always addressed as "Father X", and I think also for Orthodox priests. Protestants come in many different varieties; inquire locally. It starts to get complicated with higher clergy, since they're technically nobility and the politeness gets very thick. Again, inquire locally. But "Reverend" is almost always safe, even for a priest.

Comment: @j.r., "father" is common in Italy, too, but I assure you that cardinals like of being called "his eminence", though.

Comment: See the Wikipedia articles on [Ecclesiastical Address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ecclesiastical_address) and on [Clergy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clergy) for starters. It really depends on which particular flavor, sect, or cult you’re talking about. There can be no one answer for all this. Anything more florid than things like *Reverend* or *Father* sounds very old-fashioned and out-of-place to the American ear, full of fakery and pomp.

Comment: @J.R. Are you **sure**? Then, why are judges/justices in the U.S. supposed to be addressed as "Your Honor"? Why would clergy be any different from a politician or judge?

Comment: [See here](http://www.newportmanners.com/codesaddressing.asp).

Comment: My last reference is great. **“Q:** How would I address a letter to former President Bill Clinton and Secretary of State Hillary Clinton? **A:** *Dear President Clinton and Madame Secretary,* Thank you for...” and **“Q:** How will Former President Clinton be addressed if Hillary is President? **A:** President Bill Clinton retains the title of President, as a former president he is addressed as President Clinton and when Hillary becomes president, mail addressed to them will be sent to:
*The President and President Clinton,*
The White House, Address”. There’s lots more where those came from.

Comment: Anonymous: Yes, I'm sure. "Your Honor" is used to maintain civility in a courtroom. Most pastors would probably find titles like the ones you've listed far too pretentious for their flock (although, as @John mentions, at very high levels of the church hierarchy, things may change a bit). Most clergy I've spoken with in my lifetime prefer simpler titles like Pastor Dave, Pastor Ingqvist, Father Emil, or even, "The Padre" – at least for everyday conversation. You might be more formal if you were, say sending a formal invitation. Why different? Because priests can't put you in jail – not anymore.

Comment: In the United Kingdom, [Debrett’s](http://www.debretts.com/forms-of-address/professions/religion.aspx) is considered an authority on such things. For example, [rabbis](http://www.debretts.com/forms-of-address/professions/religion/judaism/rabbis.aspx) are addressed as *Rabbi* Cohen, or the *Rev. Rabbi* Cohen. For the highest office, though, only *His Holiness* will do, as with the Dalai Lama.

Comment: WHy are people voting to close this as too broad? Its pretty straightforward - how do you address clergy?

Comment: If Hillary is elected, Bill Clinton will be a Dowager President.

Comment: @JohnLawler I thought a dowager was by definition female.

Comment: @Mitch Because it’s too broad. There are uncountably many kinds of clergy.

Comment: @Mitch: Because it's [too broad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minister_(Christianity)); "clergy" can be the Lutheran minister, the AME worship leader, the fundamentalist Baptist preacher, the Catholic priest, the LDS bishop, the Army chaplin, the Greek Orthodox archbishop, etc. Each denomination has their own customs; each clergyman has his (or her) own personal preference.

Comment: It is always unwise to refer to someone as a mistress, particularly if she is one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general term for such titles is "honorific". See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Style_(manner_of_address)#Religious for details. There is another article on religious honorifics at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_of_religious_honorifics_and_titles but it appears to be incomplete.

Comment: Church of England parish priests were traditionally addressed as Mr. X (or Dr. if appropriate) in everyday speech, but nowadays a lot of British people seem to be adopting the American usage of "Reverend X." Of course in these more informal times many congregations will use their vicar's Christian name. It depends on what circumstances you are asking about.